# BackupWebStorage on iOS - set to none, but data still persists after deleting app from device

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, storage

We're developing an app using Ionic/Cordova that saves items to using the SecureStorage plugin. Items are saving fine, but when we uninstall the app reinstall, the items we've saved before are still there. We would like to stop this behaviour.

We found out about the BackupWebStorage property [(link)](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/ios/config.html) and have set this to `none`, however the data still persists despite this being set.

Is there anything else we can check, turn off, set in Xcode that we have to do at this point to get this to work?

Thank you,
bengrah

Comment: I forgot to mention, we're using `cordova-ios@5.1.1`

Comment: Hey @bengrah its bit late but did you find a solution for this ? I am stuck with this issue. I have added BackupWebStorage to none in every place but still its recurring.

Comment: Hi @FahadMalik - we never did manage to get a solution to this - it was definitely an issue in the original version the plugin (https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage/issues/97) but not sure if it is in the echo version (https://github.com/mibrito707/cordova-plugin-secure-storage-echo) (the original is no longer maintained)